# Inverse function theorem : Let $f:E \to R^n$ . For each $U,V$ in the construction and $x \in U$ , can we have $f'(x)$ invertible?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inverse-function

> If $f:E \to R^n$ is continuously differentiable and $f'(a)$ is invertible , $b=f(a)$.Then we can find open sets $U,V \in R^n$ such that :
>   $(1)$ $a\in U$ , $b \in V$  and $f$ is one-to-one from $U$ onto $V$ .
>   $(2)$ If $g$ is the inverse of $f$ defined in $V$ , then $g$ is continuously differentiable .

In the proof of Rudin's book , the $(U,V)$ he construct also has the property that for all $x\in U$ , we have $f'(x)$ invertible . So we have $g'(y)=\{f'(g(y))\}^{-1}$ for every $y \in V$ .
However , does this always valid for every pair of $(U,V)$ that satisfied condition $(1),(2)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because by the second condition, the inverse $g$ is differentiable; hence by the chain rule, for every $x \in U$, we have that $g'(f(x))\circ f'(x) =I$ (the identity linear transformation). In particular, $f'(x)$ has to be invertible.

Comment: $g’(f(x))\circ f’(x) = [g’\circ f\circ f’](x)$ right? Just checking my sanity here

Comment: @let'shaveabreakdown No, they're not the same thing. For starters, the composition $f \circ f'$ doesn't even make sense. If you want, you can write $g'(f(x)) \circ f'(x) = [g' \circ f](x) \circ f'(x)$. But it is important to note that $f'(x)$ itself is a linear transformation (or a matrix... I can't remember which convention Rudin took) and $g'(f(x))$ is another linear map, so we are composing the two linear maps. So, just to reiterate, $(g \circ f)'(x) = g'(f(x)) \circ f'(x) = [g' \circ f](x) \circ f'(x)$.

Comment: So how would you write $g’(f(x))\circ f’(x)$ without $\circ$ and just with embedded parentheses?

Comment: @let'shaveabreakdown That would be extremely cumbersome, and really there's no way around it... we can try to dress it up all we want but the point is, the composition is still there. Here's what I mean: define the composition map $C: L(\Bbb{R}^n) \times L(\Bbb{R}^n) \to L(\Bbb{R}^n)$ by $C(T,S) := T \circ S$. Then, $(g \circ f)'(x) = g'(f(x)) \circ f'(x) = C\left( g'(f(x)), f'(x)\right)$. This is purely in terms of parentheses, but the composition is "hidden" by virtue of the map $C$.

Comment: That’s very enlightening, thank you so much for taking the time to explain! I can’t pretend I understand it fully, but this is definitely enough information for me to get to research more deeply, which is always exciting

Comment: @let'shaveabreakdown by the way, from what I recall, Rudin's later few chapters on multivariable calculus are very bad. If you would like a careful and systematic treatment of Multivariable calculus (and Linear algebra in the beginning) from an extremely general (but detailed and clear) perspective I suggest you take a look at Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus (it is freely and legally available online).